Webots wb_robot_step and basicTimeStep
In the Webots user manual, it is mentioned that wb_robot_step should be a multiple of basicTimeStep. This indicates how many times basicTimeStep is executed within wb_robot_step.
Assuming Scenario 1: basicTimeStep = 10, wb_robot_step = 100. In this case, if the function wb_robot_step() is executed, it will execute 10 steps internally. Does the execution time of the function wb_robot_step() have any relation to the real-world time? Is the execution time of this function 100ms?
Assuming Scenario 2: What happens if I set wb_robot_step smaller than basicTimeStep, for example, wb_robot_step = 2, basicTimeStep = 10? I couldn't observe any relation in my experiments.
